# Web Service to multiply 2 2D matrix

Tags: c#, web-services

I writen method which multiply 2 Matrix:

```
[WebMethod]
    public void MultiplyMatrix(double[,] _A,double[,] _B,int _n,int _m,int _r, out double[,] C)
    {
        int n, m, r;
        n = _n;
        m = _m;
        r = _r;
        double[,] A = new double[n,m];
        double[,] B = new double[m,r];
        C = new double[n,r];
        A = _A;
        B = _B;
        try 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < r; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < m; k++)
                    {
                        C[i, j] += A[i, k] * B[k, j];   
                    }
                }
            }
        }
            catch(IndexOutOfRangeException){}
    }
```

and I wonder that in method MultiplyMatrix should be parameters out double[,] C or maybe I make a mistake?

thanks for any sugestion:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just returning one thing return a value.

i.e.:

```
public double[,]  MultiplyMatrix(
                                  double[,] _A,
                                  double[,] _B,
                                  int _n,
                                  int _m,
                                  int _r,)
```